# Extracting attachment from Email using IMAP. Do I have a parsing error?

Tags: python, email, parsing, imap

I am writing a script that will be able to extract attachments from emails and save them as a new file name to a specific directory. For some reason I have been running the code and am getting an error from the the email module saying that an object is not subscriptable. Was wondering if anyone could help me trouble shoot this issue. I know what the error means, but am pretty new to the email module so I can't really figure out what I need to do to get past it.

---

```
# Extracts Attachment and saves as new file
def get_attachment(msg):
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype() == 'multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.getfilename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(attachment_dir, fileName)
            with open(filePath, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))

        os.rename(fileName, 'SpecialSituations_P&L ' + current_date() + '.png')

con = auth(username, password, imap_url)

#Select Email Folder
con.select('INBOX')

result, data = con.fetch(b'1440','(RFC822)')
raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])

get_attachment(raw)]
```

---

ERROR MESSAGE

```
  File "extract_attachment_from_mail.py", line 45, in <module>
    raw = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Looks like `data[0]` returned `None` therefore you cannot do `data[0][1]` because you're essentially saying `None[1]` which is impossible

Comment: Type this at Python's Console to see what I mean `>>> None[1]`. Look at the error message.

Comment: You don't have a message number 1440, likely.  Is it UID 1440?

Comment: Thanks @Max. I guess my biggest problem is not understanding how to find the email I'm looking for to extract the attachment from. Eventually I want it to be the 2 most recent unread emails, but for now I was trying to find a specific one with an attachment to test the script. Can't really wrap my head around the whole email bytes thing.

Comment: Thanks for the input @FailSafe